# Reference request: Locally convex space is Hausdorff if and only if ...

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I was given the following theorem by my professor:

> Let $A$ be a locally convex space. Then $A$ is Hausdorff if and only if, for every seminorm $p$, we have that $p(x)=0$ implies that $x=0$.

If I am not mistaken, what this actually says, is that every locally convex space is Hausdorff if and only if every seminorm is also a norm (i.e. if the locally convex space is also a normed space).

Am I understanding this statement correctly?
Can anyone please provide me with a nice reference of this result?

Comment: Consider the difference between $\forall x\ne 0\ \exists p \ p(x) \ne 0$ and $\forall p\ \forall x\ne 0\   p(x) \ne 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is false, the weak topology is Haussdorff but doesn't have the given property.

What is true is that $A$ is Haussdorff if and only if for each $x \neq 0$ there exists a $p$ such that $p(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I think the statement by my professor could then be adjusted slightly to the following, which should then make it correct: 
$A$ is Hausdorff if and only if there exists a family of seminorms $G$ definining the topology such that $p(x)=0$ for every $p \in G$ implies $x=0$.
Would you agree?

Comment: @DJS Yes. That is correct.